# Java SAX parser startElement not seeing tags

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

Sample XML:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>The Channel Title Goes Here</title>
<description>
The explanation of how the items are related goes here
</description>
<link>/events</link>
<item>
<title>
<![CDATA[ some title ]]>
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</description>
<content:encoded xmlns:content="http://stuff.com">
<![CDATA[ 
    <event>
        <name>some name</name>
        <startdate>some date</startdate>
        <starttime>some time</starttime>
        <location>some place</location>
        <description></description>
    </event>
]]>
</content:encoded>
</item>
<item>
</item>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

My SAX parser `startElement` method never goes into the following `if` statement, but the sysout prints "event" to the logcat.  Why does it never find `localName.equals("event")` to be `true`?

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
{
    System.out.println(localName);

    if (localName.equals("event"))      // <-- never goes in here
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Is it something to do with the CDATA and how I set up my parser?  Here's how I instantiate everything:

```
URL sourceUrl = new URL(kEventsURL);

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

Comment: That's not really a surprise, is it? A CDATA section usually contains text that does not comply with the XML format or structure and will therefore be ignored by the parser (meaning: it's considered to be plain text). I'm not aware of a setting to change this standardized behaviour, but since in your case the CDATA section is basically another XML hierarchy, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to delegate it to another SAX parser instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) to understand why it doesn't recognize tag start. You should probably run another parser with text from element.

Comment: How would I get a string from the URL data?  I could just remove the cdata tags and parse it normally.

Comment: If you're going to remove strings you will scan string data fully once already. Also there will be some strings manipulation overhead - objects creations. But it's really minor by performance probably.

Comment: Removed the <!CDATA[ and ]]> characters and ran the parser and it worked.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "localName", try "qName"